# HTML Image Not Loading? (Please Help_

Tags: html

I am trying to code myself a website, and while just getting started was going[HTML File With the Code Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAmwz.png) to insert an image. I ran into some trouble and thought there was an easy fix, but I've been stuck on it for at least an hour now. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The `Images` folder should have a capital 'I'. Also it looks like the `Images` folder is a sibling to the 'html' folder rather than a subfolder so you should be using the relative path of `../Images/School_Mascot.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Your file's name is Images, it has a capital `I`. In your code, there is a lowercase `i` for the folder.

Comment: Please also accept our answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please, verify you folder name and call image into your html code.

[image: Folder Image]